# Is there a word for salivating in response to negative stimuli, as opposed to positive stimuli?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

Like when you smell a dead rat your mouth produces saliva and makes you spit a lot. Or when you see something gross, doesn't make you vomit, but your mouth waters you spit a lot.

Comment: Why *negative of salivate*? You are excessively salivating right?

Comment: Oh, really?....

Comment: It's a sense of disgust, not quite nausea but technically the same.

Comment: If I were to see a cat salivating at the sight of a dead rat, I'd understand that reaction. But from a human being? I think you are looking for *nausea*.

Comment: I fail to see how the example you give calls for a negative of salivate. I am also puzzled to think how *salivate* could possibly have a negative, other than *not salivate*. What would be the negative of sweat?

Comment: @WS2 *Unsweat*, obviously.

Comment: Obviously you are creating more saliva but not really anticipating to eat the dead rat.

Answer (score 1):

The condition you've described might best be called

> **si·al·or·rhe·a**  (sī-ăl′ə-rē′ə) *n.*
>   An excessive secretion of saliva.

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "sialorrhea." Retrieved April 1 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sialorrhea .)

According to the [*Farlex Partner Medical Dictionary*](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/sialism), synonyms of 'sialorrhea' include "hygrostomia, ptyalism, sialism, sialismus, sialosis".

As far as I could determine, no verb form with 'sial-' exists.

An alternative is

> **pty·a·lism**  (tī′ə-lĭz′əm) *n.*
>   Excessive flow of saliva.

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "ptyalism." Retrieved April 1 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ptyalism .)

The verb, 'ptyalize', is an obsolete medical term.

If you want to avoid words that sound clinical or technical, one term used in the past was

> **sweet-spittle**  *n. Pathol.* an increased secretion of saliva having a sweetish taste.

["sweet, adj. and adv.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195665 (accessed April 01, 2016).]

Comment: A downtick for this answer from a voter who was unable to understand the question. This prize is why Trump might be elected.

Comment: Have a neutralising upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Retch applies:

(http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/Retch)

> Retch
>
> RETCH, verb intransitive [See Reach.]
>
> To make an effort to vomit; to heave; as the stomach; to strain, as in vomiting; properly to reach.

"Heave" and "gag" fit fairly well, too.

"Drool" refers exclusively to the saliva production and dribbling, so also fits this use.

Now, as to the opposite of salivating would be dry/cotton mouth or even desalivating. Doesn't seem to fit your particulars, though.